# How to pass static argument to python threadpool map

Tags: python, multithreading

Assume I have a function that I call in a multi-threaded environment like below:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool as _thread_pool

test_data = [('hi','bye')]

def print_data(arg,first=True):
    if first:
        print(arg[0])
    else:
        print(arg[1])

with _thread_pool(32) as pool:
    pool.map(print_data,test_data)
```

now say my test_data was not only 1 element, but millions and I wanted to call the map function to always use `first=False`. Is there an easy way to do that, without adding `first=False` to every element in test_data before passing it into pool.map?

Comment: `pool.map(lambda x:print_hi(x,first=False), test_data)` maybe

Comment: `print_hi` is undefined in your code. Why is `test_data` a list with a tuple inside of it? Are you going to have millions of tuples or one tuple with millions of items?

Comment: @martineau millions of tuples, although the example is constructed.

Comment: If `print_data()` is never called in a way that the the `first` argument is `True`, it might be worthwhile remove the `if` inside it. If it is, then perhaps it would be best to have two separate functions.

Comment: @martineau admittedly the example is contrived. However, I think it's simple enough to get the point across. 
I totally agree that if it's always True or False, the function should not have the branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `functools.partial` to create another function:

```
import functools

...
    pool.map(functools.partial(print_data, first=False), test_data)
```

Comment: is this faster than applying a lamda to the function, like this 
pool.map(lambda x:print_data(x,first=False), test_data)?

Comment: May not be faster in this simple case, but has many other advantages and more powerful. There will be one day that you meet them...